# Как составить ключ для сортировки по сумме цифр?

Tags: python

Друзья, подскажите, нужно отсортировать числа в строке или листе, учитывая сумму цифр числа. Например строка 103, 90 будет отсортирована как 103, 90 тк 1+3+0 = 4, 9+0 = 9

Проблема с составлением ключа для функции sorted.

```
def valid_parentheses(string):

      return sorted(string, key=[sum(map(int, str(x))) for x in string.split(' ')])

print(valid_parentheses('103 90'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если исходные данные - числа в списке:

```
lst = [103, 50, 90, 60]
sorted_lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: sum(map(int, str(x))))
```

Если исходные данные - числа в строке, записанные через пробел:

```
nums = '103 50 90 60'
sorted_lst = sorted(map(int, nums.split()), key=lambda x: sum(map(int, str(x))))
```